# calling Elastic search with basic authentication from classic asp

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, asp-classic

using postman with basic auth set with the Url set to `myserver:9200/myindex/_search?q="testtext"` with the posttype set to `GET` returns my expected results.

I've now got a classic asp page where I call the following JavaScript function:

```
<script language="text/javascript" runat="server">

var username="elastic";
var password="changeme";

function elasticTest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myserver:9200/myindex/_search?q="testtext"',
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
            },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,throwError) {
            alert("error");
        },
    });
}

</script>
```

It fails with an error stating that I do not have the correct permissions.
and quickly highlights the **`<script language="text/javascript" runat="server">`** line. So it doesn't come from the error function.

Comment: if you are using basic auth then the url should be `'http://username:password@myserver:9200/myindex/_search?q="testtext"'`and remove the beforeSend, you wouldnt need it.

Comment: @ugosan it doesn't like that at all.

Comment: Why dont you try with the official javascript library: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js

Comment: It will work with classic asp if I do the following, but I don't think it's the best way. `Response.Buffer = true`
 `dim xml`
 `Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`

 `xml.Open "POST", "http://elastic:changeme@10.128.128.109:9200/myindex/_search?q='william'", False`
  
 `xml.Send`

 `Respose.Write xml.responseText`
 `Set xml = Nothing`